# How to get Author Attribute when it's set for TestFixture level instead of Test level?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I want to set an Author for **testFixture** and get it at runtime to be able to fetch it in my DB :

Here is the `TestFixture` class
I set Nunit attribute Author for testFixture level :

```
[TestFixture(Author = nameof(AuthorName.Eva)),MachineCategory.Filter]
public class FilterTests : WidiaTestSetup
{  

        [Test, RetryOnFailureOrException]
        public void FilterCuttingDiameter()
        { ...}
}
```

To get the test Author from **test** level I do :

```
Author = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Author").ToString()
```

But It is not working from **testFixture**
How can I do to get it from `TestFixture` level ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not a very elegant solution, reflection is probably your best bet here.

```cs
var author = GetType().CustomAttributes.First().NamedArguments.First(x => x.MemberName.Equals("Author")).TypedValue.ToString();
```

I'd suggest doing this in your OneTimeSetup to avoid incurring any unneeded costs per test.

Answer (score 1):

It's available in the `TestContext` of the fixture. Just save it somewhere in a `OneTimeSetUp` method.

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void GrabTheAuthor()
{
    _fixtureAuthor = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("Author").ToString();
}
```